# Auto leveling 6DOF Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I developing an 6DOF game. I have some problems with the auto leveling (so the ship will always goes horizontal). The auto leveling worked, but I can't turn anymore on the x-axis more than 90 degrees. The spaceship must fly free in any direction. I hope someone can help me.

```
 // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        yaw = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed;
        pitch = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed;
        roll = Input.GetAxis("Roll") * speed;

    float ver = 0;
    float up = 0;
    float hor = 0;

    up = Input.GetAxis("Up");
    hor = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    ver = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    ver *= speed * Time.deltaTime;
    up *= speed * Time.deltaTime;
    hor *= speed * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, yaw); 
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.left, pitch);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, -roll);
     
        Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.up, transform.forward);
        Quaternion rotator = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.right, cross)

        // Apply rotation
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotator * transform.rotation, Time.deltaTime);
     
    transform.Translate(hor, up, ver);

}
```

Comment: Raycast is totally the wrong way to do this.  Raycast is used to find objects on the path of the ray.  What you want to do is move ```transform.up``` toward ```Vector3.up```.

Comment: I thought Raycast is also possible. Is try this code: Quaternion rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, Vector3.up);  transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rot, Time.time * 0.001f); It still doesn't work. Do you have a code snippet as an example?

Answer (score 0):

As requested in comments (**note: untested**):

```
void Update() {

    var yaw = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    var pitch = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    var roll = Input.GetAxis("Roll");

    var up = Input.GetAxis("Up"); // better name is 'heave' (up/down)
    var hor = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); // better name is 'sway' (left/right)
    var ver = Input.GetAxis("Vertical"); // better name is 'surge' (forward/back)

    
    // If no rotation input, then 'auto-correct' for roll (up direction)
    if ( Mathf.Approximately(yaw + pitch + roll, 0)) {

        // Find what the 'up' rotation is
        var levelRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.forward, Vector3.up);

        // Apply it over time (Limit the angular change with Time.deltaTime)
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, levelRotation, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    // Else there IS input rotation, so deal with that instead.
    else {
        // Scale inputs for speed (rotation speed should probably be different from translation speed)
        yaw *= Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        pitch *= Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        roll *= Speed * Time.deltaTime;

        var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yaw, pitch, roll);

        transform.rotation *= rotation;
    }


    // Acale and apply translation
    ver *= speed * Time.deltaTime;
    up *= speed * Time.deltaTime;
    hor *= speed * Time.deltaTime;

    transform.Translate(hor, up, ver);

}
```

Comment: Still doesn't' work in 6DOF. I make some changes to var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-pitch, yaw, roll); The auto leveling is ok, but I can't turn 360 degrees in every direction. For example when I am turning in the x-axis (and I want to turn 360 degrees) it turns me back.

I think the rotation must be in local scale. I tried everything, but no correct result. What I want is the controles like the game Descent Overload, this is a 6DOF game.